# How can you tell if an app is 64 or 32 bits?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit

I have searched to find if this has been asked and I have not seen it.  There are questions asking if the OS is 64 or 32 bits.  This is not the question I am asking.

On a Windows 64 bit OS, how can you tell if an app (program) is 64 or 32 bits?
The code itself does not say and the installation does not say.

I have a 64 bit machine but I know that I have an other program that is a 32 bit loaded and it runs.  So my OS does not exclude me from having a 32 bit program.

So, how can I tell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://superuser.com/a/103073/137173

Comment: Do you want retrieve this infomation programmatically? if your answer is Yes then which language do you want to use? if you answer is No then this question does not fit in this site.

Comment: For future answer seekers, this Windows Explorer extension allows you to view 32/64 bit architecture information inside your file manager without using external tool: http://sanje2v.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/writing-property-handler-for-windows-explorermanta-property-extension/

Answer (score 1):

You can use tool such as [PE Viewer](http://www.ucware.com/apev/index.htm) to see information about EXE files.

Personally I use Altap Salamander's viewer feature to see the EXE or DLL architecture.

[image]

It is `Intel x86` for 32-bit EXEs and `AMD64` for 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze `PE` header.

It is header of any windows executable. To do that read `*.exe` as binary, take a bytes that are at offsets `0x3C` and `0x3D` the `WORD` made of these is offset of `PE` beginning.

After you have offset, validate if you are right, beginning of `PE` is `PE\0\0` (`PE` and two `NULL` symbols), just skip this indication block and read the next two bytes and make another `WORD`. It indicates target machine, if you want to check for `64-bit` it will be one of the these:

```
0x8664 - x64
0xaa64 - ARMv8 in 64-bit mode
0x0200 - Intel Itanium processor family
```

**NOTE** after you read two bytes, to make `WORD` you may need to flip them.

Also take a look at [this question with answers](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6040/8247)

And also [download PE header documentation from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have knocked up a console application utility in C# to check. It's basic but can be expanded upon.

It returns informational text to the console but also uses the exit code to indicate the type just in case you wish to use this in a batch file.

See below

Cheers

Roj

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ExeType
{
    class Program
    {
        const int st_error = 99;
        const int st_unknown = 98;
        const int st_unidentified = 97;
        const int st_not_PE_image = 96;
        const int st_Exec_x86 = 1;
        const int st_Exec_x64 = 2;

        const int st_offset = 0x3c;

        const int st_P = 0x50;
        const int st_E = 0x45;

        const int st_ind_x86_1 = 0x4c;
        const int st_ind_x86_2 = 0x1;

        const int st_ind_x64_1 = 0x64;
        const int st_ind_x64_2 = 0x86;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please specify a file");
                Environment.Exit(st_error);
            }

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(args[0]));

            byte[] block = br.ReadBytes(0x1000);

            br.Close();

            if (block.Length < st_offset+1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown");
                Environment.Exit(st_unknown);
            }

            int offset = (block[st_offset+1] << 8) + block[st_offset];

            if (block.Length < offset)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown");
                Environment.Exit(st_unknown);
            }

            int indicator1 = block[offset];
            int indicator2 = block[offset+1];

            if (indicator1 != st_P || indicator2 != st_E)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a PE format image file");
                Environment.Exit(st_not_PE_image);
            }

            offset += 4;
            indicator1 = block[offset];
            indicator2 = block[offset + 1];

            int retval = st_unidentified;

            switch (indicator1)
            {
                case st_ind_x86_1:
                    if (indicator2 == st_ind_x86_2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("32 bit");
                        retval = st_Exec_x86;
                    }
                    break;
                case st_ind_x64_1:
                    if (indicator2 == st_ind_x64_2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("64 bit");
                        retval = st_Exec_x64;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Unidentified");
                    break;
            }

            Environment.Exit( retval );
        }
    }
}
```